# Authenticating requests using the REST API with 'AWS Signature Version 4'

Tags: java, android, rest, amazon-web-services

Current System:

1. 'Amazon Web Services' as Server
2. REST Architecture
3. Using 'Retrofit' android library as HTTP client
4. PHP is used as server side scripting

Issue:

Authenticating requests using the REST API with 'AWS Signature Version 4'.

Amazon Web Services used:
EC2: Server
S3: Files Storage

AWS Android SDK:
This option is not being preferred because of library size and since
current system is in REST and using 'Retrofit' as HTTP client.

It would be good if an android/java library is there which can handle
this authentication process instead of writing the whole code altogether.

I need to communicate to PHP files which are placed in AWS EC2 and need to upload/download images from AWS S3.

Please suggest if there's any other way we could do this.

Comment: You can write it yourself.  The request signing process for [Signature Version 4 is fully documented](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html).

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? I am trying to find an OkHttp interceptor that signs the requests.